# Calculating a resonance fluorescence spectrum (Mollow Triplet)

Tags: fourier-transform, quantum-optics

I was working through a lecture on quantum optics, in which we calculate the spectrum of electric field correlations of fields produced by two level emitters. Now, the part where I got stuck was actually rather elementary I'm afraid, but I simply don't get it. In the end we find an expression for the correlation function $g(\tau)$ (The exact form probably doesn't matter, but adding it here for completeness)
[image]

Up to this point everything was fine, I understood the derivation. My teacher then went on to say that the implications are best understood by looking at the spectrum, which he defines as 
[image]
So to be clear, this is twice the real part of the integral (from 0 to infinity) of e^{i omega tau} times the correlation function. I have to admit that I don't really understand this form. The way I see it, it is the inverse fourier transform (due to no minus sign), and it is being taken twice from 0 to infinity, implying that it is even. And we only take the real part, for a reason I also don't understand.

Could someone explain to me why this exact form gives us a resonance spectrum? Should it not be a normal fourier transform (minus sign)? I don't see why the function gives above is even (it doesn't seem to be to me), so why take it from 0 to inf and multiply by two? And why are we only interested in the real part? I thought that in order to get the spectrum one should take the absolute value. However, I have to admit that I no longer remember exactly what the real part and the imaginary part of a fourier transform contain, information wise. I can't find it online either, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that this form is just a fancy way of writing a normal Fourier transform. Use the definition of the intensity correlation function
$$g^{(2)}(\tau) = \langle n(\tau) n(0) \rangle, $$
where $n(t)$ denotes the (Hermitian) intensity at the position of the detector, evaluated at time $t$ in the Heisenberg picture. The angle brackets $\langle \bullet\rangle$ denote an expectation value with respect to the quantum state. For a stationary process, one has
$$\langle A(t) B(s) \rangle = \langle A(t-s)B(0)\rangle. $$
This condition actually defines a stationary process. For example, if your dynamics is generated by a time-independent Liouvillian (e.g. a Lindblad equation), then the dynamics is stationary. Therefore we are dealing with a stationary process. Using these relations, along with the fact that $\langle A\rangle^{\ast} = \langle A^{\dagger}\rangle$, you should be able to show that
$$2 \mathrm{Re} \int_0^{\infty} e^{i\omega t} g^{(2)}(\tau) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i\omega t} g^{(2)}(\tau), $$
which is just a standard Fourier transform (up to a choice of sign convention for the complex phase).

Comment: Thank you, that actually makes a lot of sense. We did indeed start with a Lindblad equation, so that follows quite well. The sign convention is stupid I guess, that I didn't think of that. One small comment (this is unclear from the handwritten stuff above), these are actually $^{1}$ correlations, not intensity. The one looks like a two, I agree.

Comment: @user129412 Okay, well then if the operators you are dealing with are not Hermitian it's probably the case that you have the Fourier transform of an anti-commutator.